# NSURL Connection of iPhone app Download Terminating Before Completed

Tags: iphone, xcode, download, nsurlconnection

I have this bit of code to download an mp3 from the server.  All is set up with Table View parsing a podcast, and the link for the mp3 is the _entry.articleURL.  After just a few minutes, the iPhone kills the connection, and I end up with just a small portion of the mp3 downloaded.  Any ideas what may be causing this?

```
-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
{     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

             self.nameit = entry.articleTitle;
             NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleUrl];    
             NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
             __block NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

             UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance

             __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object

             background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                 // This code gets called when your app has been running in the background too long and the OS decides to kill it
                 // You might want to cancel your connection in this case, that way you won't receive delegate methods any longer.
                 [connection cancel];
                 [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                 background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid

                 //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
             }];

             self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = background_task;
             if (connection) {
                 receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
                 self.thetable = tableView;
                 self.thepath = indexPath;
             }
             else {
                 UIAlertView *cancelled = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Failed" message:@"Please check your network settings, and then retry the download." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [cancelled show];
                 [cancelled release];
             }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
progress.hidden = NO;
downloadInProgress = YES;
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:thepath.row];

self.nameit = entry.articleTitle;
downloadlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameit];
[thebar addSubview:downloadlabel];
[receivedData setLength:0];
expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[receivedData appendData:data];
float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
[progress setProgress:progressive];


}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[connection release];
UIAlertView *connectionfailed = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Failed" message:@"Please check your network settings, and then retry the download." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[connectionfailed show];
[connectionfailed release];
progress.hidden = YES;
downloadInProgress = NO;
[downloadlabel removeFromSuperview];
[thetable deselectRowAtIndexPath:thepath animated:YES]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
[connection release];



}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
return nil;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[nameit stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"]];
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[receivedData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
progress.hidden = YES;
downloadInProgress = NO;
[downloadlabel removeFromSuperview];

[thetable deselectRowAtIndexPath:thepath animated:YES]; 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

The issue is that it seems the connectionDidFinishLoading keeps getting called, even if incomplete.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to do this work - its purpose is for a completely different task (doing a bit of work after your app gets moved to the background. Your usage of this while in the foreground is most likely the reason for your problems.

What I suggest you do is go poking around on github etc for a sample Concurrent NSOperation demo project, and use those to do your asynchronous NSURLConnections.

Also, you are updating a GUI element in a view in the callbacks. Keep in mind you must be on the main thread do work with UIKit. If you need to update something, just use a block and dispatch it to the main queue to do the updating.

Comment: I had this in there so that the download could continue to go even when in the background.

Comment: I make extensive use of blocks and Concurrent NSOperations. All the example projects on github are more or less the same, mine make extensive comments on how to get the runloop and a autorelease pool setup, but in any case what you've written is quite unusual in my experience, and while you might get it to work eventually you will be on your own to do so, as I doubt anyone else is going to be able to figure it all out.